# Efficient a += b*c in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to calculate `c+= a*b` in numpy without extra temporary memory allocation/copy?
The way I understand it, to compute the expression above, numpy will use temporary memory for `a*b` and then compute `c+=tmp`.
I know we can use `np.multiply(a, b, out=c)` to calculate `c=a*b` without using extra temporary memory, but can we do something similar to do `c+=a*b`, not just `c=a*b`.

Of course, I'm using operators `+` and `*` as an example. The questions applies to any combination of `+=, -=, /=, +=, +, -, *, /, %, ...`.

Comment: if memory is a concern, then probably your best bet is just to use [numexpr](https://numexpr.readthedocs.io/projects/NumExpr3/en/latest/)

Comment: My main concern is speed. That's why I'm trying to avoid extra memory allocation and copying.

Comment: Have you profiled your code to confirm that performance here is *actually* a concern?

Comment: @Vukasin well, try out `numexpr`, but also try out the regular numpy way. Your best bet here is empirical profiling.

Comment: I didn't and I know it's not something that will eat away much time (even in application such as training a neural network). 
I'm just asking to check if numpy can support such functionality or not. It it does support, then why not use it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks. I will try it!

Comment: I think the temp space cannot be omitted, the AST for the expression will always have it!

Comment: To ensure that the data transfer is reduced, you can create a new dimension in `c` that stores the `a*b`